# Changing TweenMax Speed on effects

Tags: javascript, gsap

I am pretty new to GSAP. The following works great and changes between background images, but not sure how to speed it up so it's a little faster.

***JavaScript:***

```
var avatarAni = new TimelineMax({ paused: true, repeat: -1 });

    avatarAni.to(avatars, animDuration, {
        scaleX: 1.1,
        scaleY: 1.1,
        ease: Power3.easeIn,
        onComplete: onCompleteScaleIn
    });

    avatarAni.to(avatars, animDuration, {
        scaleX: 1.0,
        scaleY: 1.0,
        ease: Power3.easeOut
    });

    avatarAni.play();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`animDuration` is the variable you can play with. Decrease its value a little bit and *both* of your `.to()` tweens will go faster.

Otherwise, if you do not want to change individual tween values, you can use the **[`.timeScale()`](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TimelineMax/timeScale/)** property of a `TimelineMax` instance and it would speed up the `avatarAni` timeline itself. So you could do this:

```
...
avatarAni.timeScale(2);
avatarAni.play();
```

The **[documentation](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TimelineMax/timeScale/)** says:

> Factor that's used to scale time in the animation where 1 = normal speed (the default), 0.5 = half speed, 2 = double speed, etc.